# How to update a rails value using ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to learn rails and breaking stuff :)

There are two problems I am trying to solve. I want to create a dropdown that allows the user to pick the number of questions, then I want to go to these questions individually (by pressing next and previous) to fill in these questions and their answers.

I followed Ryan Bates RailsCasts: #197 Nested Model Form Part 2 to create the nested forms.

So my structure is as follows:

Quiz --> Questions --> Answers

When a user creates a new quiz, they are asked how many questions they want to create, value is sent via ajax, and then they are taken to the page for the first question for that quiz.

```
  <% f.select :number_of_questions, (1..20) %>
```

Then in the quiz controller:

```
def number_of_questions
  @number_of_questions = params[:number_of_questions]
  # create this many questions in edit and new
end

def new
  @quiz = Quiz.new
  3.times {@quiz.questions.build}  # replace 3 with number of times
end
```

I'm only doing this to learn something new.

Comment: If they're taken to a new page anyway then what's the Ajax for?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I initially wanted to create the number of forms on the quiz page.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to send it via ajax but rather as a parameter.

You have to create a form which shows a dropdown as you already did.

But if `number_of_questions` is the action which shows the form than you can remove `@number_of_questions = params[:number_of_questions]`. It does nothing other than assigning `nil` to the instance variable.

All you have to do than is to send the form to the `new` action. Just specify the `url` parameter in your `form_for` and than set the parameter instead of the 3.

**View:**

```
<%= form_for :quiz, url: path_to_new_action do |f| %>    <!-- Specify the path! -->
  <%= f.select :quantity_questions, 1..20 %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**Controller:**

```
def number_of_questions
end

def new
  @quiz = Quiz.new

  params[:question][:quantity_questions].to_i.times do
    @quiz.questions.build
  end
end
```